# Structure of amadeus api https

Tags: https, amadeus

usualy when I use API's I paste the entire url in browser and it print it out json format using json pro extension in chrome. Like this is a lot easier to copy the path of some data and render it to the page.But my problem is I don't know structure of https. I am not sure where I have to insert the key and  secret code. In command line I print all data but I cannot get the path of specific data without using json probextension. Help please. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to read the following article:
https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/guides/authorization-262

and later, review the following repository, you could tinker with the curl request here:
https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-code-examples
https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-code-examples/blob/master/airline_code_lookup/v1/get/curl/airline_code_lookup.sh